# Delete wordpress on website and replace it with django - Setting up website entirely with django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, wordpress, hosting

I own a webpage which has [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.com/support/com-vs-org/) preinstalled.
I have never done anything with it, but now it's about time. As I'm learning [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), I would like to build my webpage with it instead of using the preinstalled `wordpress`.

How do I go about it? I haven't found anything related to this topic searching the internet.

[This is the webpage](https://www.andreas-luckert.de/) with preinstalled wordpress I'm talking about.

Comment: Well, it's not really a WordPress related question but should be more around hosting / DNS question. basically, you should set up a new Django instance somewhere, and just point the domain name to the new server.

Comment: You can assume that I just have very basic knowledge on these topics. I have never worked with it, just wondering how to replace wordpress with django to design my website using django, that's all I'm striving for. The wordpress on my page is hosted by the wordpress-server then, or what kind of external server do I need for the Django Instance? Naively, I hoped that my website is just like "one server" where either wordpress or django is being deployed.

Comment: Django uses python specific infrastructure - you could find services like Heroku, Digitalocean, and so on that offer Django PAAS solutions. WordPress on the other hand runs with PHP, and most hosting providers would only support one of the options, so it's better to use a different hosting solutions for WordPress/Django in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How can I find out on which server provider my wordpress is currently deployed?

Comment: Try this - www.whoishostingthis.com

Comment: Thanks, now I've found out that my hosting provider is `netcup`.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same just 9 months ago ... you can literally start from scratch as you seem to not have too much on the wordpress page its not a big damage. Next steps: you can check if the theme you used is also available for html5 so it looks familiar and you need to choose a provider who hosts django unless you dont want to setup the server yourself. Any questions ... just ask.

Comment: I don't know much about these topics, just naively thought that on my website there is "wordpress installed", I kind of "uninstall wordpress" and "install django". I don't know about using additional servers for deploying the web frameworks, is this necessary and even separate from my website? PS: I don't care about the current content on the website, I haven't done basically anything on it and thus there's nothing to be preserved as far as I'm concerned.